# Send message of System.String is wrapping xml

Tags: biztalk

I have a simple odx that constructs a message of type System.String, then pushes out through a send port.

The content of the output message is good except it's prefixed with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>
```

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>
Good plain text format here
```

How can I prevent the content being wrapped with the  without having to resort to a custom pipeline component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the string directly to the XLANGMessage in a helper library (as if you were writing binary data to a message), and make sure to use a pass through transmit pipeline.   I'm not sure if this would work with a System.String message or not, but I know it'd work with an XmlDocument message.

e.g.

```
public static void LoadXLANGMsgFromString(string source, XLANGMessage dest)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, false, true))
    {
        dest[0].LoadFrom(ms);
    }
}
```

You need to use that constructor of MemoryStream to make sure the base data stream is exposed for XLANGs to make use of.  Then, in an Orchestration message assignment shape:

```
msg = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
Helper.LoadXLANGMsgFromString("Good plain text format here", msg);
```

Comment: I must be missing something in the context here - I'm getting the error "cannot convert from System.Xml.XmlDocument to Microsoft.XLANGs.Basetypes.XLANGMessage" when trying the same code in the expression editor. What could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Orchestration is expected to work with xml only typed or untyped. With string type, it automatically creates a xml wrapper over it. I think there will not be any way around it, unless you want to use a custom send pipeline component to take out the xml tag before writing.