# How to remove <string> in SMS

Tags: sms, biztalk

I have a BizTalk solution that would send an SMS to our client once their phone has been registered in our system. Unfortunately the SMS would contain XML tags in it like this.

< string>Your PIN is 1234.< /string>

How can i remove the < string> tag in the SMS? I have made sure the Message Type in my Orchestration is correct and that I have the below code in my Construct Message shape.

```
strCellNos = classHelper.getElement(SendSMStoCustomerRequest, "cell_number");
strSMS = classHelper.getElement(SendSMStoCustomerRequest, "message");
msg_SendSMStoCustomer.parameter = strSMS;
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.Subject) = "Test Message for " + strCellNos ;
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.From) = "noreply@none.com";
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.SMTPHost) = "SMTPHOST";
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.EmailBodyText) = strSMS ;
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.EmailBodyTextCharset)="UTF-8";
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.SMTPAuthenticate) = 0;
```

Comment: Should you use the text property of the element rather than the element itself?

Comment: Brody, I'm not sure what you mean exactly since I'm very new at BizTalk. How can use the text property as you ask?

Comment: When you use getElement it may be returning an entire element which when you use as a string is returning the wrapping element tags.  You need to get the element text by using getElement(...).Text or something like that (maybe innerText) which will return just the inner text value of the element.

Comment: I'm already using innerText and my code look like below:

       public string getElement(System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlMessage, string node)
        {
            string xmlVal = string.Empty;
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlMessage.GetElementTag(node);
            foreach (XmlNode xmlElement in nodeList)
            {
                xmlVal = xmlElement.InnerText;
            }
            return xmlVal;
        }

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll repeat my answer from MSDN here.

Just treat the outgoing Message as a Flat File using a Flat File Schema and the Flat File Assembler in the Pipeline.

Trust me, this is very, very easy.  All these things you're trying are to fix problems you shouldn't even have in the first place.

Please, take a step back and create msg_SendSMStoCustomer as a Flat File Type in the beginning.  Then, it will just work, I promise you.

Comment: Please understand, there's nothing special about this.  It's just a 1 field Flat Field message.  You're way over thinking this.  There's plenty of articles and articles on creating Flat Files.

Comment: These are the steps I performed in order to create and map the flat file schema.
1. Created a FlatFile Schema.
2. Created a Biztalk Mapping that will map the XML schema where the message will come from to the Flat File Schema.
3. Mapped the Flat File Schema in Flat File Assembler in my send pipeline under Document Schema field.
4. Mapped the Flat File Schema in my Multi-Part Message in Orchestration.
5. In the Construct Message shape I added this code on the next Comment section.

Comment: PhoneNum = classHelper.getElementByTag(msg_SendSMStoCustomer, "phone");
Message = classHelper.getElementByTag(msg_SendSMStoCustomer, "message");

msg_SendSMStoCustomer.parameter = strMessage;
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.Subject) = "Test Message for " + PhoneNum;
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.From) = "noreply@none.com";
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.SMTPHost) = "SMTPHOST";
msg_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.SMTPAuthenticate) = 0;

***The classHelper.getElementByTag is a class that will extract the Phone Number and the message strings which came from the request schema.

Comment: And unfortunately I encountered this error upon testing the solution.


There was a failure executing the send pipeline: "SendSMS.Pipelines" Source: "Flat file assembler" Send Port: "SendSMS.SendPort" URI: "mailto:99999999@noreply.com" Reason: The document type "string" does not match any of the given schemas.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Sorry, but it's difficult to help when you don't follow our advice.  This was addressed specifically in the other thread.  You can't use the String Type on the Send Port.  This is a regular Flat File message, there's nothing special about it.

Comment: So I rehashed everything and created a Flat File Schema. I've also added Flat File Assembler in my pipeline. However, I get this error message in BizTalk "Flat file schema must have the 'Root Reference' property set to a record name." thus the message was suspended. I'm not sure if it's really related to the Root Reference of my Flat File Schema but I made sure that the value of my Root Reference is "SendSMS" not just "Root" which id the default.

Comment: Yes, the Root Reference property on the <Schema> node.  You pick this off a list and it would be whatever the actual Root Element is.  There's usually one one choice.

Comment: Ok so I finally got the <string> removed from the SMS. However this time there's an encrypted text showing in the message. Something like this "{C5B3EAF6-2CF6-40AA-9118-20430843A0D0} Your One Time PIN is 123456." Would you know what's causing the {C5B3EAF6-2CF6-40AA-9118-20430843A0D0}?

Comment: Then it would be best tom mark the Answer in this thread and open an new one.  The two cannot be related.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at a similar question here: [Send message of System.String is wrapping xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216428/send-message-of-system-string-is-wrapping-xml)

Basically, BizTalk will wrap a `string` node around your System.String variables if you assign it to a message.

The proposed answer in the linked question provides a helper method which will circumvent this.

Comment: So I've added the code in my helper and the below code in the Orchestration Message Assignment shape: Message = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
Helper.H13_SendSMStoCustomer.LoadXLANGMsgFromString("test", Message); but I keep encountering error "argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' to 'Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.XLANGMessage'" and now I'm stuck once again. Please help as I have been sitting on this issue for 3 days now.

Comment: You can't do that.  If you just create the outgoing message correctly in the beginning, none of these will be an issue.