# Globally Unique ID showing in SMS

Tags: text, sms, biztalk

I have a flat file schema which contains phonenum and textmsg fields. We use the phonenum field where we'll be sending the textmsg via BizTalk. We are successful in passing the message and was able to receive the text message. However in the text message there's an encrypted text which is unnecessary and must be removed. The message looked like

> {C5B3EAF6-2CF6-40AA-9118-20430843A0D0} Your One Time PIN is 123456.

How can we remove the {C5B3EAF6-2CF6-40AA-9118-20430843A0D0}? Is there something we must configure in Pipeline or Orchestration?

This is our code in Construct Message:

```
msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer.parameter = msgRcv_FlatFileSchema;
InMessage = xpath(msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer.parameter,"string(//*[local-name()='textmsg'])");
msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.EmailBodyText) = InMessage;
```

- Wherein msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer.parameter is a Multipart Message Type that will serve as body of the message we pass to BizTalk.
- We declaired msgRcv_FlatFileSchema as Message Type and mapped our Flat File Schema in it.
- InMessage is a variable we declaired as System.Xml.XmlDocument.
- The textmsg in the xpath code is the message body we declaired in our flat file schema.
- We use Dynamic Send Port here and use Custom Pipeline. Inside our custom pipeline is a Flat File Assembler in the Assembler part. While MIME/SMIME encoder in the Encode section. We just use all default settings in our Flat File Assembler and MIME/SMIME encoder.

Comment: Can you show us some code / configuration of how you are passing the message?   Without that it is very hard to work out what us going on.  That {.....} is called a GUID (Globally Unique ID) and as messages flow through BizTalk they are given various GUIDs.  So it is not encrypted text (so I've removed that tag from your question)

Comment: Please use the edit link under the question to add more details, rather than in the comments.

Comment: Why are you MIME Encoding?  If it's just SMS, the text content is all you need.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019444/how-to-remove-string-in-sms.  Looks like he is using a email to SMS gateway.

Comment: As Johns-305 has said, try it without the MIME Encoding.  Just a flat file assembler.

Comment: Also why are you trying to flatten the file inside the Orchestration using  XPath.  Just pass the Flat File Schema message in XML Format to the send port and let it flatten it.  Your flat file schema should just have the one node, being the bodytext

Comment: I needed 2 nodes in my flat file schema since that's on the requirements. One for the phone number and the other for the body of the message. We'll use the phone number later on where we can send the message itself. Nevertheless this has been resolved by adding the Subject line.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by using an XML Schema instead of Flat File. Then I added some class to convert String to RawString. Got the solution on this site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36210/Sending-an-HTML-formatted-e-mail-message-from-Bi. And of course the Construct Message should look like this:

```
stringPhoneNum = classHelper.getElement(msgRcv_SendSMStoCustomer, "phoneNum");
stringMessageBody = classHelper.getElement(msgRcv_SendSMStoCustomer, "messageBody");
msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer.multiPartMessage = new Microsoft.BizTalk.XlangCustomFormatters.RawString(stringMessageBody);

SMTPUtils.Part.SetContentType(msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer.multiPartMessage,"text/html");
msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.From) = "noreply@noone.com";
msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.Subject) = " ";
msgSnd_SendSMStoCustomer(SMTP.SMTPHost) = "host";
```

I intentionally left SMTP.Subject as " " because if it's null or not declared at all then it will be preempted by the GUID. Also I got the code for classHelper.getElement in the web. Just search for "how to convert xml to string" and you should be good.